# Get day of week

Tags: math, calendar, gregorian-calendar

Task: need to get day of week from and date on proleptic Gregorian calendar(it can be 2009, 935, 2, 342 BP and any date on time axis).

Can not find a mathematical model anywhere.
Maybe someone faced with this problem before?

P.S. Implementation language is not important

Comment: And to repeat the answer-that-wasn't an answer because it should have been a comment: I think you are looking for [Zeller's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

Comment: And to boddah: feel free to post a *proper* answer; e.g. explain how Zeller's congruence would help here, perhaps even with a sample implementation. Just linking to a Wikipedia page is not enough of an answer, however.

Comment: I am looking for a math model, maybe some explanation how simple Gregorian and proleptic Gregorian calendar related for. I found zeller's conguruence, but can't understand how it's works.

Comment: Making the one-liner answer that was posted all the more unhelpful then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If January and February are considered as the last two months of the prior year, the weekday differs from the beginning of March by ⌊(13m-1)/5)⌋ days; adjust for leap years and leap centuries to compute the day of the week:

```
function weekday(ccyy, mm, dd) # zeller's congruence
    days := ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur"]
    if mm < 3 then mm, ccyy := mm + 10, ccyy - 1 else mm := mm - 2
    cc, yy := ccyy // 100, ccyy % 100
    day := (dd + (13 * mm - 1) // 5 + yy + yy // 4 + cc // 4 - 2 * cc) % 7
    return days[day] || "day"
```

This varies slightly for dates prior to adoption of the Gregorian calendar.